# Avoid code duplication of try/except blocks, from a class

Tags: python, class, exception, try-catch, contextmanager

I have a class `Test` which is a subclass of another one (which is already a context manager, I chose `nullcontext` here for simplicity).

**How to avoid to repeat the `try`/`except` blocks, and have this directly *in the class* definition?**

Unlike [Avoiding Multiple Try/Except blocks in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54959693/avoiding-multiple-try-except-blocks-in-python) and its answers, I'd like to do it with the class instead of creating a new function.

Example:

```
import contextlib

class Test(contextlib.nullcontext):
    pass

try:
    with Test('abc') as t1:
        do_something(t1)
        do_something_else()   
except ValueError:      # these exceptions are thrown from Test's parent     
    print('a')          # class/context-manager methods  (nullcontext in this example)
except KeyError:
    print('b')

try:
    with Test('def') as t2:
        do_something(t2)
        do_this(t2)
except ValueError:
    print('a')
except KeyError:
    print('b')
```

TL;DR: How to move the `try:`, `except ValueError:`, `except KeyError:` into the class `Test`?

Comment: I have the motivation to make a function or put your code in a loop due to seeing code duplication. Is there something you are not showing which would change my motivation?

Comment: @quamrana Not a loop: I simplified my real situation, but they don't do the same things, and they have different arguments, imagine different `Test(param1=..., param2=...)` calls, and the block `pass` very different.

Comment: I think you've over-simplified your example,  where are you expecting a ValueError or KeyError to be thrown from?  If the error occurs inside Test.method() why not make test.method handle the error itself?

Comment: @JeffUK That's the precise point, I should add this: these exceptions are thrown from the parent class/context-manager (`nullcontext` in my example).

Comment: When are they thrown?  When the object is created?  If they're thrown from __init__ could you could over-ride __init__, wrapping a call to parent __init__ with error handling?

Comment: @JeffUK Yes during the init, or potentially during other methods. I edited the question to add this useful information in the code.

Comment: You can nest the context managers.
This post is about this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720179/nesting-python-context-managers

Comment: @JeffUK I think your idea (wrap a call to parent init inside Test.__init__) makes sense. Do you want to post an answer with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does putting the code in `__init__` solve your problem?

```py
import contextlib


class Test(contextlib.nullcontext):
    def __init__(self, abc, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        try:
            if abc == 'def':
                raise ValueError("VALUEERROR")
            elif abc == 'ghi':
                raise KeyError("KEYERROR")
            else:
                print("OK")
        except ValueError:
            print('a')
        except KeyError:
            print('b')


x1 = Test('abc')
x2 = Test('def')
x3 = Test('ghi')
```

Comment: I think it's good! Maybe just add `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)` to pass the arguments to the parent class/context manager.

Comment: An even better way would be to be able to catch *any* error linked to instances of Test (and not only `__init__`) but I don't know if it's possible directly in the class itself...

Comment: @Basj You're right about ```*args``` and ```**kwargs```, I added them. For your second point, that would require modifying a method that would be called no matter the method called, and that's not possible in Python (or I would be surprised if it was). You could work around it with a single public method ```execute```, or named along those lines, that would take a string as argument and call the private method of that name ; you would then have a single entry point and you could put ```try/except``` blocks in it. That sounds dubious to me, but it could be worth it.

Comment: Thank you @OctaveL! A last thing: `Test` is  a context manager, that I want to use with `with Test() as t1: t1.dosomething()` (see original question). How to make that this context `t1` terminates without an error, instead of `raise`, when for example `abc == 'def'` in your example, so that `t1.dosomething()` is *not* executed? I tried to replace `raise ...` with `self.__exit__()` but it does not work.

Comment: @Basj That's complex. I've pulled it off, but it's a really nasty solution: replacing every method of the class with a lambda that simply ```pass```es, and replacing the methods back in the ```__exit___``` call. I'm afraid I can't come up with much better right now, but I can share my solution if you want.

Comment: Thank you @OctaveL! No, I think it would be too hack-ish, I'll try to do another way.

Comment: @Basj Is wrapping your ```with Test() as t1: t1.dosomething()``` in a ```try/catch``` block an option? It could catch any exception, or a custom one made specifically for errors in the ```__init__```. I know you want to avoid ```raise```s, but I can't think of better suited solutions.

Comment: Yes I'll do like this @OctaveL, it seems the best option.